# Scraping in PHP

Tags: php, web-scraping, web-crawler, instagram

I want to build a code in which if I give the username it dump me the below highlighted value(no. of followers) from the page source of any instagram user.
I know about curl and DOM concept a bit.[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
function callInstagram($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(CURLOPT_URL => $url, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2)) $result = curl_exec($ch); curl_close($ch); return $result; }

$url = "instagram.com/xyz/";;
$dom = new domDocument();
$dom->loadHTML(callInstagram($url));
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('script');
print_r($tables); ?> Still building
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: <?php  
function callInstagram($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2))
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 
    return $result;
} 
$url = "https://www.instagram.com/ravij28/";
$dom = new domDocument();  
$dom->loadHTML(callInstagram($url)); 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('script'); 
print_r($tables);
?>
Still building

Comment: update your code in your question, not in comment.

Comment: Your result is JSON, so you should use something like [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: but I am still stucked in how to use DOM with a url which is originally a HTML

Comment: What's your question about this?

Answer (score 0):

Look like you are trying to get instagram's data.

It's better to use instragram's API to achieve your goal.

link: https://www.instagram.com/developer/

**Edit:**

Another way assume you can get string of all html.

Next, use regex to extract json string out. 
You can use this regex: `_sharedData = (.*);`

Finally, use `json_decode` to convert string to json.

Comment: After recent changes in their permission review its very difficult to get the APIs and I just want to add one feature in my project

Comment: Oh, got it. However, the result you want is inside `<script>` tag's variable, it hard to get data from there.

Comment: isn't there any way its possible?

Comment: Edited, have a look

Comment: This does not look like an answer after all - how is `_sharedData = (.*);` a regular expression that works when using PHP?